# Is there something I am missing in this, because I am getting error on HackerRank while it's working in JupyterLab?

Tags: python

I am making a simple program to check if a UID is valid or not.
It must contain at 2 least uppercase English alphabet characters.
It must contain at 3 least digits (0 - 9).
It should only contain alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z & 0-9 ).
No character should repeat.
There must be exactly characters in a valid UID.

And this is the code I'm using. It works perfectly fine in my JupyterLab but it's giving me the Type Error on Hackerrank.

```py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = int(input("Enter the number of test cases: "))
        q = str(input("Enter the UID: "))
    
    cap_count = 0
    num_count = 0
        
    for x in q:
        if x.isupper():
            cap_count = cap_count+1
        if cap_count > 1 and x.isnumeric():
            num_count = num_count+1
                
    if (len(q) == 10) and (q.isalnum()) and (len(q) == len(set(q))) and (cap_count > 1) and (num_count > 2):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

**IT's supposed to return valid or not valid**
**Here is the complete Traceback**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Solution.py", line 17, in 
> if (len(q) == 10) and (q.isalnum()) and (len(q) == len(set(q))) (cap_count > 1) and (num_count > 2):
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

I know it's not the cleanest code that you guys have seen. But could really use the insight on why it works perfectly well on Jupiterlab and not on hackerrank even when both use python3.

Also, I'm taking input n cause it's required as one of the inputs, but no use for it.

Comment: it works on my machine. Surely something's wrong with either the code or the way HackerRank interprets the code

Comment: The code you posted contains an `and` between `len(set(q)))` and `(cap_count > 1)`. The code in the error message does not. Therefore I conclude that the code you submitted to HackerRank wasn't the same as the one you posted here (and tried in JupyterLab).

Comment: Did you copy and paste the traceback right? Because it seems like you're missing a `and` between `(len(q) == len(set(q))) (cap_count > 1)`.